# Getting a word predecent a regular expression match?

Tags: regex

I want to evaluate an expression similar to the following:

**this is the street blue**

You can determine a color using a regular expression a bit rough as follows:

**.? (cyan | green | red | blue)**

So far so good, however, how I can determine the object which causes the color? That is, in this case I want to reclaim the word "Street", but it could be "Car", "Arrow" or any other noun.

In short, is it possible to construct a regular expression that once found a specific point (math) in this case the color, you can get the last word, which corresponds to the object on which color is applied, or what is the same , the word before the match found by the regular expression?

Comment: Why not just add another matching block before the color match, ie `([^\s+])\s+(cyan|green|red|blue)`?

Comment: @JackManey, you may want to move your first '+'.  :c)

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - Oops, right you are. Unfortunately, it's too late to edit...so, for the OP, that regex should be `([^\s]+)\s+(cyan|green|red|blue)`.

Comment: Mmm I understand your idea, but imagine you want to identify a type of road (for instance), once you recognize the name it must be recognized if it is a street, avenue, highway, road, etc ..... in example the color "Blue" is the name of the object focal, is the element that allows me to match, once found its predecessor look to find out which type is .... because it could be a blue street, avenue blue highway blue ......
I hope I explained .... do not know if my logic to solve this problem is correct also ....

Comment: The first brackets will give you a match, that contains the word in front of the color.

Comment: Jack, Frankie---That example is very close to what I am looking ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
(\w+)\s+(blue|green|cyan)
```

The word before the color match would be in capture group 1.

Java test:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(blue|green|cyan)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("This is the street blue");
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the first `\s+`, do you?

Comment: true, you don't. And it wouldn't work in all cases with that either.

Answer (score 0):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to get the word before a color (with [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
/\b.+\b(?=\s+(cyan|green|red|blue))/
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression is the one that best fits what you are looking for, surely need further data processing, but it is really useful.

Thank you all for your comments